# Why am i getting all my products and not only one in my view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

In my detail-tickets view i want to show all the data of a loaded product with all its fields, but when i want to view the detail i get all my products and no only the one product that belongs to that ticket.

So the following is how im storing my tickets:

```
 public function store(Request $request){
        /*dd($request->all());*/
        $ticket = new Ticket();
        

        if($request->file('file')){
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file->move('storage/', $filename);
            $ticket->file = $filename;
        }
        
        /*$ticket->cuenta_id = $request->cuenta_id;*/
        $ticket->contact_id = $request->contact_id;
        $ticket->statusTicket_id = $request->statusTicket_id;
        $ticket->typeTicket_id = $request->typeTicket_id;
        $ticket->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;        
        
        $ticket->product_id = $request->product_id;
        $ticket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
        $ticket->accesories = $request->accesories;
                                
        $ticket->entry = Carbon::parse ( $request->entry)->toDateString();
        $ticket->deliver = Carbon::parse ($request->deliver)->toDateString();       
               
      
                    
        $ticket->save();            
                        
          

        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('tickets.view');
    }
```

And this is my detail method:

```
public function detail($id){
        $detailData = Ticket::find($id);
        $detailData['contacts'] = Contact::all();
        $detailData['products'] = Product::all();
        $detailData['ptypes'] = Ptype::all();
        $detailData['brands'] = Brand::all();
        $detailData['models'] = ModelP::all();

        return view('backend.ticket.detail-ticket', compact('detailData'));
    }
```

So in my view im passing my product as the following:

```
@foreach($detailData['products'] as $product)
       <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="product_id">Producto</label>
          <input type="text" name="product_id" value="{{$product->ptype->productType . ", " . $product->marca->brandName . " " . $product->modelo->modelName}}" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
```

@endforeach

And this is an image of how it is bringing me data:

[image]

There should be only one product but instead i have all my product list.

Any idea what im doing wrong while passing the data to my view?

Answer (score 2):

in this line:

```
 $detailData['products'] = Product::all();
```

you are loading All products not only the wanted product ...

it should be:

```
 $detailData['products'] = Product::find($detailData->product_id);
```

Comment: But now im getting another error in my view,  `Trying to get property 'ptype' of non-object `

Comment: because there is no need for @foreach($detailData['products'] as $product)

Comment: $detailData['products']  will have only one record

Comment: Removing the foreach and passing it like this i still have the same error.  `value="{{$detailData->ptype->productType . ", " . $detailData->marca->brandName . " " . $detailData->modelo->modelName}}"`